# Can a malware infect my main drive when I'm using a different OS on a external drive?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, security, encryption, liveusb

I've installed Linux Mint to an external drive to visit sites I find suspicious. My main drive has Windows 11 installed on it with a Microsoft account and a password. So my question is:

Can a malware possibly infect my main drive when I'm using Linux Mint on an external drive ? I must also add that I unmounted my main drive from Linux Mint drive settings.(So not physically) Does using an account and a password on Windows 11 encrypt my main drive ? If so is this encryption enough to completely seperate two drives ? Thanks for all the answers in advance.

Note : I know VMs are much more suitable for this kind of use case but my machine isn't exactly top of the line and most VMs I've tried were unusably slow.

Comment: I would say it's possible, although quite unlikely. I mean, nothing other than the privilege / permission configuration on the Linux installation prevents a program from performing a block-level write to the other drive, but I doubt that there are any/many malware that is actually an executable on Linux and is also designed to *modify* a Windows installation (like, inject another Windows executable that runs in your next Windows boot), but on other hand I can imagine there are programs that would simply attempt to e.g. wipe / "ransom-crypt" all the drives available on the system.

Comment: Note that encryption can probably prevent attempts of modification mentioned above (although not block-level write *to the drive itself*; at least not BitLocker-ish ones), but user account and password hardly matters when Windows is not on, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can. If malware gains root access to some system running on your computer, it can discover and mount your Windows (or other) partition and do anything with it.

However.

General "wide audience" malware targets mostly "low hanging fruits" in the form of non-patched systems with known 0-day vulnerabilities, and while there are plenty of them, nobody will bother to make the malware that is able to do at least the following:

1. Gain Linux root privileges, AND
2. Discover other systems on the machine, AND
3. Infect them from within this Linux instance it is running from.

On the other hand, if you're billionaire, you will inevitably catch some personal attention of various subjects who'll target specifically you. In this case, they *may* target your particular setup and then expect if something is possible to do to cut some of your money it will be done, because the quite hard (read: very costly) problem of writing custom malware tailored to your specific case will still be worth it.

---

In general, to have an isolated system which is not able to do anything with your main system, better run it in the VM (and run it so it doesn't keep any changes after installation — making it impossible for the malware to persist even in the VM). Yes, there will be some performance loss, but that's the price for the invulnerability that you'll have against any malware.